# C# PInvoke flushall not giving any output, return value is 2

Tags: c#, pinvoke, dllimport

I was trying to follow a simple tutorial on C# PInvoke, and created the following program that should output the Test string.

```
[DllImport("msvcrt.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern int puts(string c);

[DllImport("msvcrt.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
internal static extern int _flushall();

public static void Main()
{
    puts("Test");
    int x = _flushall();

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

When I run the program, I don't see any output in the Console window, or the Output window in Visual Studio.

The return value from the _flushall call is 2.  I have not yet been able to find a good reference on msvcrt.dll to see what functions/entry points are available, and what the return values mean.

Comment: There's more to it, the CRT needs to be initialized first.  In particular, the stdout stream needs to be opened before puts() can write anything.  That's taken care of in a C program, not in a C# program.  You could replace "msvcrt.dll" with "msvcr110_clr0400.dll" in a .NET 4.5 program and see it work.

Comment: If you're learning about P/Invoke, you might want to take a look here: http://www.pinvoke.net/

Comment: Hans has an answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22071964/platform-pinvoke-tutorial-msdn/22074254#22074254